# How to check if ANY key in dict is empty? Python

Tags: python, dictionary, google-sheets

I am iterating over a spreadsheet (specifically google sheets) and it returns a *list of dictionaries*.

I am able to access each dict by using ...

```
sheet = client.open('test').sheet1
list = sheet.get_all_records()
for row in list:
```

In each dictionary, I need to run a function that checks to see if a specific key is empty, if it is then it returns that dictionary that contains the empty key. I am able to do this by using ...

```
for row in list:
   if bool(row['name']) == False:
      print(row)
```

My question is how would I check to see if ANY dictionary has the key 'name' empty, if no dict has the key 'name' empty, run a command?

Hope this made sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `any` function to check the entire collection:

```
if any([bool(r['name']) == False for r in list]):
    print('at least one')
```

@Mad Physicist made a good point that is worth examining.

In Python, variable values can be converted to boolean and evaluated based on their 'truthiness'. If using the `bool` function to convert a value, `''`, `None`, `0`, and `False` all convert to `False`. Any other value converts to `True`.

The same conversion happens when using `not`. `bool(x)==False` is the same as `not x`

With this in mind, you can make the code more concise:

```
if any([not r['name'] for r in list]):
    print('at least one')
```

As @MP also mentioned, you can reverse the logic using `all`:

```
if not all([r['name'] for r in list]):
    print('at least one')
```

`all` will implicitly convert each value to a boolean

---

On a side note, don't use `list` as a variable name since it is a type in Python.

Comment: You don't need explicit `bool`, and testing `== False` is not idiomatic either. Just `not r['name']` is fine.

Comment: Also, `not all(r['name'] for r in ...)`

Comment: I appreciate the answer and the tips! Anything to improve my code helps tremendously.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, I like

```py
empty = filter(
    lambda row: not row[“name”], 
    my_list
)

if len(empty):
  return empty

# do stuff
```